# If a patient arrives at the ER unconscious and needs immediate surgery, will they be put under general anesthesia?

Tags: surgery, anesthesia

I can't seem to find an answer to this question anywhere, but I'm sure that there's some kind of procedure for this situation. Assuming attempts at resuscitation fail, what is the next step for a patient who needs immediate surgery? Does general anesthesia pose additional risks to an already unconscious patient?

Comment: a) unconscious is not dead. Resuscitation is only performed when the patient‘s circulatory system collapsed. b) yes, it will. There is a difference between unconscious and surgery-unconscious. For a surgery, a few body reflexes like gagging will be suppressed, so the G.A. is usually deeper than unconsciousness, although that may vary.